# RxJava : How to send some additional info to subscriber

Tags: java, android, rx-java

I have created a simple method, which will send message ( as Object ) to given subject. At other end subscriber will consume the object.

Am going to use same subject for multiple consumers, hence while sending message want to send some additional info i.e. 200, 300. So consumer can filter out un-relevant messages. But somehow not able to figure out how to do that.

Additional info (int parameter)  can be handled at `postToSubject` method and at `action1` but not sure how to place it here `subject.onNext(object)`

Please suggest if you can think any solution.

```
public void postToSubject(Object object, Subject subject) {
    Observable<Object> observable = Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<Object>() {
        @Override
        public void call(Subscriber<? super Object> subscriber) {
            subscriber.onNext(object);
            subscriber.onCompleted();
        }
    });
    observable.subscribe(new Action1() {
        @Override
        public void call(Object object) {
            subject.onNext(object);
        }
    });
}
```

Above method is called as below ( from an Android Activity, objective is to send item to subject. Subject will be returned by second argument in the method )

[image: Method call]

At another Android Component Class ( inherited from Linear Layout ) , this message will be consumed as below. If I can get additional info i.e. 200, 300 , I will filter out and put onNext() inside it. This is the way I can think of a solution, however a RxJava expert may give a good solution.

[image: consume message]

**Answer :**

Additional Info passed through onNext() as below, subscriber will check using `if (object instanceof Integer)` and put the logic to fetch the next value returned by next onNext()

[image: Result]

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Could you add a bit more code to help us understand you intention. Don't worry if it doesn't compile.

Comment: @Bohemian - thank you for formatting and your interest.. have attached complete relevant code 1)method 2) method call 3) consumption .. let me know please if you need more details..FYI, this working flawlessly, however due to multiple possible consumer, I need to filter it with additional parameters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I would not use `Object` as parameter/message type because it is too generic. Make some base class, say `Item`, carrying basic information.

Second, create subclasses of the `Item`, say `MenuItem`, `ButtonItem`, `ParametrizedItem`, and so on. Each subtype can carry additional information.

Third, this is what `postToSubject()` should look like:

```
public void postToSubject(Item object, Subject<Item> subject) {
    subject.onNext(object);
}
```

(no need for `Observable.create`...)

Fourth, on consumer side use `filter()` operator:

```
subject
    .filter(i -> i instanceof MenuItem)
    .subscribe(menuItemSubscriber);
subject
    .filter(i -> i instanceof ParametrizedItem)
    .subscribe(paramertizedItemSubscriber);
```

Now that each particular subscriber knows what subtype items it is going to receive, it can safely cast to that subtype, and extract additional information pertaining to that subtype.

Comment: Thanks for good suggestion, I am incorporating in my code. However seems my issue still remain there.. within same subclass say MenuItem.. I need to choose one subscriber out of many, in order to do that I need to send additional values.. i.e. 200 & 300.. Is there a way to send additional values and filter out based on those values..

Comment: @Girish You can filter on whatever predicate. For example: `.filter(i -> i.getParam() >= 200 && i.getParam() < 300)`. Note I am using Java 8 lambda notation here, in earlier Javas you should use anonymous classes instead.

Comment: Thanks again, sent additional info with one more onNext(), please see Answer in question itself.  MenuItem doens't have all info, hence had to sent additional info separately i.e.200. Your suggestion was really very helpful , and given me more understanding of RxJava.